# Return type of operator= overloading and string values

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class AAA {
public:
  char* str;

  AAA(const char* s) { /* Constructor */ }

  AAA operator=(AAA& ref) {
    delete[] str;
    this->str = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
    strcpy(this->str, ref.str);
    return *this;
  }
};

int main() {
  AAA a1("fst");
  AAA a2("scd");
  a1 = a2;
  std::cout << a1.str << "\n";
}
```

In `operator=()` if I set return type to object instead of reference(like above code), nothing is output. If I delete `return *this;` and change return type to `void`, the value of `a1.str` is printed well.

My Question is: Why is there a problem if the return type is object although there is no problem when return type is `void`? Regardless of the type of return value, it seems that copying strings is already done by strcpy(). In this case, I think I don't have to set return type as a reference...

Comment: This code has so many faults.  One is that you don't have a destructor, thus memory leaks all over the place.  Second, an assignment operator's purpose is to "update" an existing object, not replace it with a brand new object.  Third, you don't check for self-assignment, thus you're deleting the memory of the same object.  Fourth, you delete `str` before you are sure `new` returns without failure, thus your object will now be corrupted if `new` throws an exception.  In short, this code would fail a code review very easily.

Comment: The code also aborts with a core dump on my machine. I think we're well into the realm of undefined behavior right now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks. I just omitted destructor in this code. How to I check self-assignment? Do I have to use try~catch outside of `new`?

Comment: @NBlizz -- you check for self-assignment by comparing if `this` is equal to the address of the passed-in reference.  If it is, then you just return `*this`.  However if you used the *copy-swap* idiom, there isn't a need to check for self-assignment, except for optimization purposes.  You are also missing the copy constructor.  But in general, why are you trying to disprove or go against sound practices?  Return a reference, plain and simple.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "comparing if this is equal to the address of the passed-in reference" Is this mean I have to compare memory address assigned in `this` and `ref`?

Comment: @NBlizz -- `if (this != &ref) { do rest of code } return *this;`. Also, your code fails on this `AAA a1("fst"); AAA a2 = a1;`, all due to a lack of a user-defined copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues here.
Your constructor does not do anything.It should initialize `str`

```
AAA(const char* s) 
{
   str = new char[strlen(s)+1];
   strcpy(str,s); 
}
```

Then

```
this->str = new char[sizeof(str) + 1];
```

should be

```
this->str = new char[strlen(ref.str) + 1];
```

otherwise you are `strcpy`ing into memory that does not belong to you because `sizeof(str)` will just give you size of a `char *` and you try to copy `ref.str` into this memory.Moreover you should not be deleting the existing object in assignment operator at all.You should update it.

You don't have a destructor to free the memory

```
~AAA(){delete[] str;}
```

Comment: Thanks. "Moreover you should not be deleting the existing object in assignment operator at all." Are you saying about `delete[] str;`? I added it because If I copy `a2` to `a1` then link to `a1`'s original `name` is broken so it occurs memory leaks.

Comment: If you `strcpy()` `a2` to `a1` the link to `a1`'s original memory is not broken.

Comment: Given that the question is about the assignment operator and its return type, it would be good to point out the serious flaw in the assignment operator's return type.